# Specifying width of gravatar img in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, width, image-size, gravatar

Would there possibly be a way I could specify the width for a gravatar img instead of just :size => x

```
<%= gravatar_for user, :size => 125, :class => "indexlist" %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. To confirm this, take a look here: http://en.gravatar.com/site/implement/images/

> **Size**
>
> By default, images are presented at 80px by 80px if no size parameter
>   is supplied. You may request a specific image size, which will be
>   dynamically delivered from Gravatar by using the s= or size= parameter
>   and passing a single pixel dimension (***since the images are square***).

Only the size (s) parameter is exposed by their API.

[http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/296f29c92c1561c79e034df64dc19f56?s=128](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/296f29c92c1561c79e034df64dc19f56?s=128&d=identicon&r=PG)